# How to check the function's return value if true or false

Tags: jquery, forms, if-statement

I have a function here that validate fields in a form if they are empty.

```
function ValidateForm()
{
    jQuery('span.error_msg').hide();
   var success = true;
    jQuery("#shippingF input").each(function()
        {
            if(jQuery(this).val()=="")
            {
                jQuery(this).next().show();
                success = false;
            }
    });
    return success;
}
```

Now I wanted to use that function here:

```
function post(url,formId) {
      jQuery("#process").html('<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/co/ajax-loader.gif'; ?>" alt="loading" title="ajax-loader" width="16" height="16" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-134">');
     jQuery.post(url, jQuery('#' + formId).serialize(), function(d) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#scrollhere").offset().top},'slow');
        jQuery("#response").html('<center><p style="height:820px"><span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;font: 11px arial,verdana,sans-serif;"><b>Loading available payment getaways..</b></span><br/><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/co/8-1.gif'; ?>" width="220" height="19" /></p></center>');
        jQuery("#response").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/checkout_payment.php'; ?>", function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
        jQuery("#response").attr("style","height:1030px");
    });
}
```

I tried it and I come up with this.

```
function post(url,formId) {
 ValidateForm();
 if(ValidateForm() == 'false') {
   jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#shippingF").offset().top},'slow');
 } else {
      jQuery("#process").html('<img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/co/ajax-loader.gif'; ?>" alt="loading" title="ajax-loader" width="16" height="16" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-134">');
     jQuery.post(url, jQuery('#' + formId).serialize(), function(d) {
        jQuery('html,body').animate({scrollTop: jQuery("#scrollhere").offset().top},'slow');
        jQuery("#response").html('<center><p style="height:820px"><span style="color:black;font-weight:bold;font: 11px arial,verdana,sans-serif;"><b>Loading available payment getaways..</b></span><br/><img src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/images/co/8-1.gif'; ?>" width="220" height="19" /></p></center>');
        jQuery("#response").load("<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl').'/wp-content/plugins/'.basename(dirname(__FILE__)).'/checkout_payment.php'; ?>", function() { Cufon.refresh(); });
        jQuery("#response").attr("style","height:1030px");
    });
 }
}
```

The problem is that, the validation is working.. however, `.post()` function runs even though there is empty field. I guess its on the if/else condition.. is there a better way to accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there a reason you are calling ValidateForm twice?

Comment: The problem is that, if i don't include `ValidateForm();` on the `post()` function.. the error messages does not show..

Comment: It's already being called inside the if. You don't have to call it again before that.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
false != 'false'
```

For good measures, put the result of validate into a variable to avoid double validation and use that in the IF statement. Like this:

```
var result = ValidateForm();
if(result == false) {
...
}
```

Answer (score 12):

You don't need to call `ValidateForm()` twice, as you are above. You can just do

```
if(!ValidateForm()){
..
} else ...
```

I think that will solve the issue as above it looks like your comparing `true/false` to the string equivalent `'false'`.

Comment: The problem is that, if i don't include `ValidateForm();` on the `post()` function.. the error messages does not show..

Comment: In your example the if statement will always be false, because your function returns true or false, it will NEVER return 'false'. Remove the single quotes from your code that are around 'false' and it will work. However, the suggestions I have made will improve your code - address that after you've fixed your code though.

Comment: Using .length on something that can be undefined is dangerous. when it is, in fact, undefined, it will return the error "cannot call length on undefined" or something similar. Hard to see as in this particular case it would cause a page refresh.

Answer (score 5):

you're comparing the result against a string ('false') not the built-in negative constant (false)

just use

```
if(ValidateForm() == false) {
```

or better yet

```
if(!ValidateForm()) {
```

also why are you calling validateForm twice?

Comment: The problem is that, if i don't include `ValidateForm();` on the `post()` function.. the error messages does not show..

Answer (score 1):

Wrong syntax. You can't compare a Boolean to a string like "false" or "true". In your case, just test it's inverse:

```
if(!ValidateForm()) { ...
```

You *could* test against the constant false, but it's rather ugly and generally frowned upon:

```
if(ValidateForm() == false) { ...
```

Answer (score 0):

`ValidateForm` returns `boolean`,not a `string`.
When you do this `if(ValidateForm() == 'false')`, is the same of `if(false == 'false')`, which is not true.

```
function post(url, formId) {
    if(!ValidateForm()) {
        // False
    } else {
        // True
    }
}
```